# AngularJS: Adding new routes dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

As we use, `$routeProvider` in config method, as of my knowledge `$route` is a provider.

So, I tried adding new routes to `$route` in my controller:

After configuring and bootstrapping the application, somewhere in my controller, I tried this:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope,$route) {
  $route.routes['/newRoute'] = { template : 'hey, this is dynamically added route' };
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work. why?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can only configure the routes via your ngapp config function only, so you can't just add routes dynamically in runtime.
also $route is a service.

Comment: $route is not a service, it is a provider which is why we have $routeProvider injected into config block.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route - and i quote from angular documentation: "The $route service". i think you are confusing what is a service and what is a provider. a provider is used to configure a service and not vice versa.

Comment: Yes, basically factories, services, providers are called as services. $route is created using app.provider function, and that is why we are able to configure $route service using $routeProvider. So Now in my code, I am trying to inject new route into $route dynamically

Comment: sorry, you can't do that. docs clearly state that you can only define routes via config function. even if you find a hack, in next version it might not work. don't go there. also with single page apps, not sure you can't define all in begining.